# MS Unity fails right after initialization

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container

Here's the code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMapper, CustomMapper>();
        container.RegisterType<ISessionLoginInfo, CustomSession>();
        IDateTimeProvider dtp = DateTimeProvider.Current;
        var cc = container.RegisterInstance<IDateTimeProvider>(dtp);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
 }
```

Right at the last curly bracket I get this exception:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Could not load type 'Custom.Shared.IDateTimeProvider' from assembly 'Custom.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Custom.Shared.IDateTimeProvider' from assembly 'Custom.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The assembly Custom.Shared is laid in the same folder with main web app assembly. The interface IDateTimeProvider and the corresponding class DateTimeProvider are placed in the forementioned assembly Custom.Shared in the namespace Custom.Shared. Also if I eliminate the line with RegisterInstance() and create an instance of class DateTimeProvider, the error disappears. What did I do wrong and how to make the DI initialization correctly?

Comment: Show `IDateTimeProvider ` and `DateTimeProvider` definition

Comment: namespace Custom.Shared
{
    public interface IDateTimeProvider
    {
        DateTime Today { get; }
        DateTime Now { get; }

        DateTime BeginOfMonth { get; }

        DateTime EndOfMonth { get; }
        DateTime EndOfToday { get; }
    }
}

public  abstract class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider, IDisposable
    {
...
}